# any way to delay code execution until page is opened

Tags: gwt

Hi we have a gwt app hosted on google app engine.

In one of the page bound to an entry point class (using root panel id) we call a rpc service to get some data.

The problem I am observing is that when even the home page is loaded that time the entry module class bound to another page gets instantiated and thus the service is called un-necessary.

any options to defer this behavior until the page is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the code under the clause like shown below fixed the issue

```
if(RootPanel.get("login") !=null){
            //moved here
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data for the page in the onLoad method instead of in the constructor so that the data isn't loaded till after the widget is attached to the DOM.